Remapping iSCSI boot LUN
Task: Rebuild Splunk server with SLES15 on our new HPE DL380 Gen10 using iSCSI boot LUN for the OS with a separate iSCSI data LUN for Splunk data storage (hot/warm bucket)
Old Server:

SLES12 HPE DL380 Gen9 (iSCSI shared data LUN)
10G Fiber card 2-port SFP+ adapter

New Server:

SLES15 HPE DL380 Gen10 (Embedded NIC, 2 Copper-ethernet)

I built the new server using iSCSI boot LUN on the embedded Ethernet NIC Port 1, installed Splunk, configured it appropriately, and ready for migration.
Upon the migration, I was told to move the 10G card from the old server to the new server and re-map the LUN to the initiator on the fiber card.
(installed 10G card on new server, connected 2 fiber cables to each SFP)
New server: HPE BIOS > Network Options > iSCSI Config >

deleted the previous iSCSI attempts that were assigned to the Embedded Copper NICs
created new iSCSI attempts assigned to the 10G-port 2 (boot order is showing iSCSI boot on port 2 for some reason)
a. changed the initiator IP-address from the new-server-ip (.65) to old-server-ip (.49)(we want the new server to retain the old server's hostname & ip-address to minimize other env changes)
b. save changes/reboot

The SUSE splash screen pops up but I am getting error messages stating:
Warning: iscsiadm: Could not get list of targets from firmware. (err 21)
only other thing I can think of is maybe the SLES15 needs the 10G drivers? (which means I need to re-cable, re-configure iSCSI, download/install drivers and then switch back to the fiber card)
-_-  did i just answer my own question?
